# After upgrade Grails 2.1 very slow to compile gsps on Mac Os X (Resources/Less plugin)

Tags: performance, memory, gsp, grails-2.0

We've notice that our stack is very slow in compiling gsp files after recently upgrading from 1.37 -> 2.1. It seems very intermittent - if I restart my Mac and start up my stack - page loading is fine or if I leave it overnight, otherwise I'll be half way through the day and suddenly pages taking minutes to start up.

**Resources/Less Plugin?**

We're using the resources plugin + less (recently added) - so it could be that, but one our team members runs on Linux and isn't experiencing any problems.

**Memory?**

In researching a solution noticed that a lot of people are saying Grails 2 is much more memory hungry... My stack running with settings below:

```
/Library/Java/Home/bin/java -server -Xmx768M -Xms768M -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xdock:name=Grails -Xdock:icon=/Users/andrewbredon/springsource/grails-2.1.0/media/icons/grails.icns -Xms512M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -classpath /Users/andrewbredon/springsource/grails-2.1.0/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars/groovy-all-1.8.6.jar:/Users/andrewbredon/springsource/grails-2.1.0/dist/grails-bootstrap-2.1.0.jar:/System/Library/Java/Support -Dgrails.home=/Users/andrewbredon/springsource/grails-2.1.0 -Dtools.jar=/Library/Java/Home/lib/tools.jar org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --main org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner --conf /Users/andrewbredon/springsource/grails-2.1.0/conf/groovy-starter.conf --classpath   console
```

Anyone experiencing similar issues? Anyone got any ideas?